# Mixing forms in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

In my app users can register information about a tournament. If the user is a paying customer, she can fill in additional info, otherwise the fields for the additional info are unavailable (visible but disabled).

I laid this out as two objects: `Tournament` and `TournamentExtras` where the former `has_one :tournament_extras` and the latter `belongs_to :tournament`. `Tournament` also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :tournament_extras`.

I would like this to show up as a single form. The fields in the two objects are related, meaning you can add a start date (to `Tournament`) but only paying customers can add an end date (to `TournamentExtras`) but since the two fields are logically realted, they should show up after eachother in the form.

How do I do this?

I tried opening the `form_for` and `fields_for` loops withing eachother (before adding any fields) hoping that I could add any field whereever I like. That didn't work; apparently you can't reference the form object within the fields loop(?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form_form and fields_for should work with each other.

Somewhat of a skeleton for this is:

```
form_for(@tournament) do |f|
  f.fields_for(@tournament.tournament_extra) do |g|
  end
end
```

Comment: It works, thanks. It didn't work for me to begin with because of some naming stuff, I guess.